# jQuery UI DateRangePicker startDate and endDate on load

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, daterangepicker

I have embedded the jQuery UI DateRangePicker from [Tamble jquery-ui-daterangepicker](https://tamble.github.io/jquery-ui-daterangepicker/)

And it works as expected but I would like to add pre selected range when present onload to it. As per API description I have tried the option setRange but either I am missing something or my start and end formating is not correct.

[CodePen Example](http://codepen.io/bintux/pen/NdzWaz)

**JS**

```
$(function() {
    $("#e1").daterangepicker({
    initialText : 'Select period...',   
    setRange({"start":"2016-11-02", "end":"2017-01-20"}) // I tried different variations with and without quotes as well

    });
});
```

**HTML**

```
<input id="e1" name="e1" >
```

Comment: .daterangepicker('setRange', {start:"2016-11-02", end:"2017-01-20"}); add this to $("#e1")   more help https://tamble.github.io/jquery-ui-daterangepicker/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setRange` is a Method, not a option. So maybe this code works:

```
$(function() {
    $("#e1")
    .daterangepicker({
        initialText : 'Select period...'
    })
    .daterangepicker('setRange', {start:"2016-11-02", end:"2017-01-20"});
});
```

Look at the example on the docs:
https://tamble.github.io/jquery-ui-daterangepicker/#programmatic

EDIT:
it looks like that you always need a `new Date();` object for it.
So Your Code should be:

```
$(function() {
    $("#e1")
    .daterangepicker({
        initialText : 'Select period...'
    })
    .daterangepicker('setRange', {
      start: new Date("2016-11-02"), 
      end: new Date("2017-01-20")
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you. I tried this but it is not setting the range. Do I maybe call this later when the page is completely loaded?

Comment: no not needed, your `$(function() {});` waited that the DOM is loaded. Maybe you must use the `Date` Object?

Comment: That did the trick - updated my codepen - thank you very much :)

Answer (score 0):

You have putted attributes inside " ". Replcae your jQuery with this::

```
$(function() {
    $("#e1").daterangepicker({
    initialText : 'Select period...',   
    setRange({start:"2016-11-02", end:"2017-01-20"})    
    });
});
```

Hope it will work.